# Kendo Grid change value using outside textbox search

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, cell

I have a simple kendo grid, and I would like to change value in this grid while I enter primary key in a textbox to search.

[Demo Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFb66.jpg)
I use Uid to change its column value and make checkbox checked. it really worked but after I mouse clicked value changed cell it return null. even I clicked save button the cell value return null.

Is there any other way to change the cell value without click event?

thanks for help in advance.

```js
    function check() {
            var s = "";
            var user = "@User.Identity.Name";
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); 
            $.each(grid.tbody.find('tr'),function(){
                var model = grid.dataItem(this);
                $('[data-uid='+model.uid+']').removeClass("k-state-selected");
                if(model.SampleId==$("#BarCode").val()){
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
                    alert(rowIdx);
                    alert($(this).closest("tr").SamplingUser);
                    grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + model.uid + "'] td:eq(4)").text(user);
                    grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + model.uid + "'] [type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
                }
            });
            barcodeclear();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make changes in grid html and also in data source in the configureGridProperties function.

```
 var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            ////....
            dataBound: function () { setTimeout(configureGridProperties, 1); },
....

function configureGridProperties(e){
// apply your logics here.
}
```